# HQL Update with join (Avoid subquery)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

i have two huge tables and they have a relation between together.
how to write update two tables with join criteria together and good performance and avoid subquery.
i know to can do this by following example :

```
update product set isOK=1 where id in (select F_ProductID from sales )
```

but above example haven't good performance because this usen't the index.
and i know we can do this by using native query but i have an another problem with it.

Comment: Have you tried batch updates? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: no, are you sure batch update has good performance?
when i use batch operation in my transactions, flushing takes time, and this is unpleasant. but i think you helped me for this, because i don't checked batch update for this yet
however thanks .

Comment: For some bulk operations native sql is better, but you indicated you can not use native. Also for bulk operations, the flushing allows you to optimize between size of memory footprint and speed of operation. You decide how big your batch will be.

Comment: yes, native is good but it will damages jpa cache, and i have to evict the cache.